# Html checkbox binding

Tags: asp.net

To bind values to checkbox list I used the following code and It;'s working fine

```
   CheckBoxList1.DataSource = languagesPair;
   CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Key";
   CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "Value";
   CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

Instead of using asp control 'CheckBoxList' I need to use html check box.By using html check box how can I Implement the above functionality.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: NO, You can't bind HTML controls the way of asp control.

Comment: So how can I populate html checkbox dynamically

Comment: Simple, instantiate a `CheckBox` control and add to the `Controls` collection of some control in the page. You will need to know about  [dynamic controls and asp page-life cycle](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx) too.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for that. Check this example code

```
$("#chk1").data("Score", 3);
$("#chk2").data("Score", 1);
$("#chk3").data("Score", 2);
$("#chk4").data("Score", 5);

$("#checks :checkbox").change(function(e){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        alert("checked Score: " + $(this).data("Score"));
    else
        alert("not checked Score: " + $(this).data("Score"));
});
```

[data binding(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/n6cmg/1/). All credits goes for [BrunoLM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340760/brunolm).